# How to list Chocolatey packages already installed and newer version available from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, chocolatey

I have the following packages installed with Chocolatey.

choco list

```
> choco list
Chocolatey v0.9.9.2                                      
adobereader 11.0.10                                      
ccleaner 5.03.5128                                       
chocolatey 0.9.9.2                                       
ConEmu 14.9.23.0                                         
gimp 2.8.14.1                                            
git 1.9.5.20150114
```

One week later the GIMP package updated to 2.9 and the Git package is updated to 1.9.6 on the chocolatey.org website, but other packages are not updated.

Two weeks later I need to run a command in cmd to show the following result:

```
> some command
git current local version (1.9.5), latest version (1.9.6) is available for upgrade
gimp current local version (2.8), latest version (2.9) is available for upgrade
```

What is the good way to compose such command? (Or if there is a command option built into Chocolatey itself, what it would be?)

Comment: `choco list` without `--localonly` freezes (Resuming with Ctrl+c), is this wanted?

Comment: @Timo it doesn't freeze actually, it might just take a long time to gather all available packages

Comment: `choco list --localonly` now fails with `Invalid argument --localonly. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.`

Comment: Re my previous comment - apparently the default behaviour of `choco list` is now only to list installed packages, so it has the same effect that `choco list --localonly` used to.

Comment: @AJM thank you for the input, I updated the question to keep up with the version 2 default behavior.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

**Note**: You likely need to do the following commands in an administrative cmd/powershell prompt.

If you have choco 0.9.9.6+, you can use the `outdated` command.

```
choco outdated
```

If you have 0.9.9+ installed:

```
choco upgrade all --noop
```

If you have version 0.9.8.33 or below installed:

```
choco version all
```

Following that, if you actually want to upgrade - you can follow with:

```
cup all -y
```

**Note:** `-y` will only work with 0.9.8.33+.

Comment: Just a note that `choco version command is deprecated and will be
 removed in version 1.0.0`. While the recommendation from that error is to use `choco upgrade pkgname --noop` the outdated command seems to work nicely as well.

Comment: That seems like a step backwards from a readability perspective to me.

Answer (score 29):

Just run the case, and **choco** said I should use this

```
choco list -lo
```

That did the trick for me, so here 2c from me.

Comment: That gives me this error: `Invalid argument -lo. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.`

Answer (score 4):

## Use "cver"

The quickest way if you want to find only the local packages installed is to issue the following command to a DOS  prompt:

```
cver all -localonly
```

Or even easier to remember and type:

```
cver all -lo
```

This avoids unnecessary querying.

Comment: The question is to distinguish outdated packages from latest ones. With cver all -localonly this command, we will get outdated packages and latest packages mixed and do not achieve the purpose of finding outdated packages. This answer should for question "how to show local packages?" but not this question.

Comment: interesting since i must have missed that, I landed here trying to solve an installed package dilemma, where this question helped but didn't lead to the solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Just a simple list of installed packages. BTW, `choco version` is deprecated, and `choco list -localonly` works the same way, now.

Comment: `choco list -localonly` (or `-lo`) is actually better than `cver all -lo`, as it lists all of my installed packages ("24 packages installed"), whereas `cver` only shows a partial list ("20 packages installed"?!). Use: `choco list -lo`.

Answer (score 4):

Addition from @feventcoder

`choco version all` will result you a warning of

> DEPRECATION NOTICE - `choco version` command is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0.0. Please use `choco upgrade <pgkname> --noop` instead.

So it mean you should learn that it might not support the `version` command anymore.

Sure that you need to upgrade your chocolatey version to 0.9.9+ or latest.

By the command `choco upgrade chocolatey`

And then call `cup all -y` to install all upgrade to your system.